# Find the Lowest between 2 Conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I want to find the highest value between the previous `inside_bar` and `longCondition`.

```
inside_bar = high <= high[1] and low >= low[1] 

longCondition = ta.crossover(a, b)
```

The logic is when `longCondition` happens, I want to find the previous `inside_bar` (which formed before `longCondition`) and find the highest bar value between them.

Here's a screenshot for better understanding:
https://prnt.sc/qtrgEnl6lHx6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a `var` variables. Just reset it when it is an inside bar and check its value when your condition is `true`.

```
var highest_val = high

if (inside_bar)
    highest_val := high      // Reset
else
    if (high > highest_val)  // Update
        highest_val := high

// Check the value of highest_val when longCondition is true
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the code. But unfortunately it's not what I was looking for. I don't want the high of the inside bar but the highest value between the inside bar and longCondition. for example, lets assume, the longCondition has triggered now but the previous inside bar formed 'n' bars back before this longCondition. I would like to find the highest value between this longCondition and the previous inside bar that formed 'n' bars back. Hope I am clear. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/qtrgEnl6lHx6

Comment: Did you try the code? It should do what you are asking for.

Comment: Just plot `highest_val` and see how it works.

Comment: Hello again, I just tired and it plots wrong. Here a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/eqJAoWfLnMOG

Comment: It seems like if the longCondition is triggered on an Inside bar, the code take this inside bar instead of the previous one. How to make it use the previous inside bar instead of the latest one?

Comment: Add an if check and use `highest_val[1]` if it is an inside bar..

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much. I did this, x = longCondition and inside_bar ? highest_val[1] : longCondition and not inside_bar ? highest_val : na