# Mark highest value using plotshape when EMAs cross

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I have checked a lot of issues on StackOverflow, and I still cannot put it together.

First of all, anyone who helps - thanks in advance. I really want to understand the depth of this.

The problem: I need to get where the ema10 and ema20 cross over and cross under. Then I need to get the highest high value (and the bar having that value) between a crossover and a crossunder. And I need to mark this bar using plotshape. Can anyone help with what I'm not doing correctly?
Right now, all the bars are marked.

```
ema1 = ta.ema(close, 10)
ema2 = ta.ema(close, 20)
plot(ema1, color = color.black)
plot(ema2, color = color.purple)

crossUp = ta.crossover(ema1, ema2)
crossDown = ta.crossunder(ema1, ema2)


highest_pine(src, len) =>
    max = src[0]
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] > max
            max := src[i]
    max

HH = 0.0
HH := highest_pine(high, ta.barssince(crossUp))
plot(HH, color = color.green)

plotshape(HH,text="Pe",style=shape.labeldown,size=size.small,offset=0,color=color.green,textcolor=color.white,location=location.abovebar)
```

This is what I would need. Instead of the circle, I want to use plotshape there.
[image]

Comment: You cannot mark that bar with `plotshape()`. You cannot dynamically position the shapes with `plotshape()`. Your only option is using `label`s.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412664/find-the-lowest-between-2-conditions/76412703#76412703) question is pretty much asking the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @vitruvius that's helpful information. I'm doing something wrong there, I've tried to use the code from the resource you linked, but I still cannot put it together using labels. Can anyone help me, please?
To create labels I used this one https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Text_and_shapes.html